# Can't send Authorization header with my request

Tags: swift, http-headers, authorization, alamofire

I have a request endpoint for sylius [API](http://%20http://demo.sylius.com/api/v1/taxons) when I set the content-type header with application/json and the Authorization header with the exact value Bearer SampleToken through postman it responds fine with the intended response but when I try to set the request authorization header through URLRequest it gives me a response

```
{
"error" = "access_denied";
"error_description" = "OAuth2 authentication required";
```

}

when I monitor the request through charles I've noticed that the Authorization header is stripped off. I've tried many various ways to set the authorization header but with no luck.

```
func getTotalProducts(page:String){
let urlPath="https://demo.sylius.com/api/v2/taxons"
var request = URLRequest(url:  NSURL(string: urlPath)! as URL)
request.httpMethod = "GET"

request.setValue("Bearer SampleToken", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

Alamofire.request(request)
    .responseJSON { response in
        switch(response.result){
        case .success(let value):
            print(value)
            break
        case .failure(let error):
            print("something went wrong \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }.session.finishTasksAndInvalidate()
```

}

The original postman request:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using Alamofire, why not simplify things?

```
let url = "https://demo.sylius.com/api/v2/taxons"

    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Authorization": "Bearer SampleToken",
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    ]

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch(response.result){
            case .success(let value):
                print(value)
                break
            case .failure(let error):
                print("something went wrong \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }.session.finishTasksAndInvalidate()
```